# Marketo API Custom Data

Tags: json, api, marketo

I am using the Marketo API V1 to get lead data from a customers Marketo account. I have successfully connected to the API (by going through their documentation).

I can get data for a single lead however it only displays the default data (id, firstName, lastName, email) and I know there are a lot of custom data fields (company, salutation, jobTitle etc.) but this does not show from the API - do you know how I can access this custom data?

Below is the API URL I am using which works fine just not showing all the data I require:

```
https://<<url>>/rest/v1/leads.json?access_token=<<token>>&filterType=email&filterValues=oliver@test.com
```

This returns:

```
{"requestId":"1261b#14f40fc3156","result":[{"id":2755951,"updatedAt":"2015-08-18T10:58:42Z","lastName":"wells","email":"oliver@test.com","createdAt":"2015-06-02T09:36:48Z","firstName":"oliver"}],"success":true}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a parameter, 'fields', which has a comma-separated list of field names to retrieve a given set of fields: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-filter-type/  See example 2, there.

Comment: I believe you meant http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/createupdate-leads/? Either way, that answered my question! I just needed nudging in the right direction and you did just that so thank you.

Comment: Indeed I did, Carl. Fixed the mistake.